# pandas bar plot cuts off ends of x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame and want a fairly simple, horizonal bar chart. However, the edges of the x-axis are too tight and my values for the first and last item are cut off:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3))
df.columns = ['col1','col2','col3']
df.index = ['ind1','ind2','ind3','ind4','ind5','ind6','ind7','ind8','ind9','ind10']
df['col4'] = 0.5
df.drop('col4',axis=1).plot.bar(figsize=(15,8));
df['col4'].plot(kind='line',color='black',linestyle='dashed',label='All-time average',legend=True);
```

The chart looks like this in Jupyter Notebook

[image]

What change is needed to extend the x-axis. Most questions on this seem to cover continuous data where you can set an x_lim but I have a categorical x-axis.

Thanks

Comment: You can still set the xlim to `(-1, len(df)+1)` or whatever suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly: `plt.xlim((-0.5, len(df)-0.5));`